# Why does my custom mouse cursor revert back to normal in Unity?

Tags: unity, macos

I have set the mouse to be a custom cursor under Edit > Project Settings > Player. (I set the cursor with script originally and had the same problem.) In the editor it shows up as the system cursor. When I run my game it shows the custom cursor for only as long as I don't move the mouse or click a button.

But, interestingly, if I hold down the middle mouse button in the editor it will show up as a custom cursor! Any ideas? I have the texture set to cursor, clamp, point, and read/write is enabled.

Comment: Does this occur only in play mode in the editor, or also in an exported standalone build?

Comment: I restarted my computer and the issue is fixed, so it must have been a bug in my OS.  Should I delete the question?

Comment: You can delete it, or post your solution as an answer, if you think it might help others who encounter a similar bug.